# Workflow related to field update scenarios

Tags: workflow

If we create2 work flows( field update)on same object which workflow rules will exceute first ?

Answer (score 0):

The order of execution of multiple Workflows on same object is not confirmed. It would be better to use a Trigger or PB(by adding multiple nodes as per order required) instead of workflow if your scenario is dependent on order of execution.

Comment: Welcome. If this answer is useful then mark it as a best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Description:-**

> We have created multiple workflow rules with similar criteria that are
>   going to trigger simultaneously for the same object; we also have
>   multiple actions triggering and we would like to know if there's going
>   to be any particular order of execution on both workflow rules and
>   workflow actions once they kick off.

**Resolution:-**

> Note: Salesforce does not support or guarantee the order of execution
>   of workflow rules.

- The same is true for workflow actions, the order in which individual
  actions and types of actions are executed is not guaranteed. However,
  field update actions are executed first, followed by other actions.
- Please do not rely on any logic based on order of execution that you
  may obtain from debug logs, for example, as we do not guarantee that
  the execution of individual workflows would be the same the next time
  the workflow and actions are triggered.

Here are some ideas you can vote related to this question:-

1. [Specify Order of Workflows](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqWFAA0)
2. [Control order of execution for process actions](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CRz5QAG)

Reference:-

1. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212758&type=1
2. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&type=5

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Welcome :) @user60023